# It says there are only 996MB free space of my home partition, but the pantheon-files tells me that there are 98.2G free out of 1.9TB

Tags: disk-management

[image]

It says there is only 996.7MB left of the home partition, but in the pantheon-files, it tells me that there are 98.2GB free out of 1.9TB.

The output of df -h: (I have deleted some files)

```
檔案系統          容量   已用  可用  已用% 掛載點
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G    0% /dev
tmpfs           364M  6.2M  357M    2% /run
/dev/sdb2        28G   11G   17G   39% /
tmpfs           1.8G   24M  1.8G    2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       75M   75M     0  100% /snap/ubuntu-core/423
/dev/sdb4       1.8T  1.7T  4.2G  100% /home
/dev/sdb1       285M  8.2M  277M    3% /boot/efi
cgmfs           100K     0  100K    0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           364M   64K  364M    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1       917G  756G  115G   87% /media/laichiaheng/66418ba9-d180-4fe1-a2b7-8bc097bb50f1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please post the output of df -h ?

Edit:
Please Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249387/df-h-used-space-avail-free-space-is-less-than-the-total-size-of-home) link.

> By default, ext2/3/4 filesystems reserve 5% of the space to be useable
>   only by root. This is to avoid a normal user completely filling the
>   disk which would then cause system components to fail whenever they
>   next needed to write to the disk. You can see the number of reserved
>   blocks (and lots of other information about the filesystem) by doing:
>   sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda8

Comment: I had deleted some files, so it shows me there are 4.2G left.

Comment: But why does the pantheon-files shows me that there are 98.2GB left?

Comment: That's the 5% of the 1.9TByte

Comment: Will it cause some problem if I set the reserved fraction to zero when the root partition and home partition are seperated?

Comment: For a separeted /home partition it 's probably safe. But saving space for important root processes (and possible rescue actions) is one good reason not to do it. You can make it less but it seems that it doesn't solve your low disk space problem. In the near future you will have to face that again.

Comment: _But saving space for important root processes (and possible rescue actions) is one good reason not to do it. You can make it less but it seems that it doesn't solve your low disk space problem. In the near future you will have to face that again_ That's for not seperated /home partition!